# submit data to shiny to create data frame and then write the data frame to file

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm new to shiny. I am wondering how can I use "textInput" to submit three strings to shiny server to create a data frame and then write this data frame to local file.

Here are my scripts. But it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**UI.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  fluidRow(

    absolutePanel(

      helpText(h5("Submit new gene.")),
      wellPanel(
        column(4, textInput('symsub', "Gene symbol",value="")),
        column(4, textInput('msusub', "MSU genomic locus",value="")),
        column(4, textInput('rapsub', "RAPdb genomic locus",value="")),
        actionButton("submit1", strong("Submit"))
      ),

      textOutput("mytext20"),

      p(HTML("<b><div style='background-color:#FADDF2;border:1px solid
             blue;'></div></b>")),
      br(),

      right=5, left=10
    )
  )

))
```

**server.R**

```
write.gene <- function(df) {
  write.table(df, file="gene.info", sep="\t", quote=F, row.names=F)
}


#### Shiny
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  geneNew <- reactive({
    if (input$submit1>0) {
      df.gene <- data.frame(Symbol=input$symsub, MSU=input$msusub, RAPdb=input$rapsub,
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      write.gene(df.gene)
    } else {NULL}
  })

  output$mytext20 = renderText({
    input$submit1
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reactive conductor:

```
  geneNew <- reactive({
    if (input$submit1>0) {
      df.gene <- data.frame(Symbol=input$symsub, MSU=input$msusub, RAPdb=input$rapsub,
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      write.gene(df.gene)
    } else {NULL}
  })
```

is called nowhere in your code, hence it is never executed. Use an observer instead :

```
  observe({
    if (input$submit1>0) {
      df.gene <- data.frame(Symbol=input$symsub, MSU=input$msusub, RAPdb=input$rapsub,
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
      write.gene(df.gene)
    } else {NULL}
  })
```